# Please suggest parameters for 0.5 mm diameter nozzle

Tags: fdm

I am building an FDM machine on my own. I am not using any commercial software. So I have a lot of questions regarding the right parameters to choose. I am having 0.5 mm diameter nozzle. What are the parameters that I am supposed to choose? The general parameters that I need to know are:

1. Extruder head speed (mm/s)
2. Layer thickness (mm.)
3. Road width (mm)
4. Filament feed rate (mm/s)

Comment: What do you mean by you are not using any commercial software?

Comment: Hello Sri!  Welcome to the 3D Printing SE Site.  I hope that you will find this a great source of information to help you with your projects and also a place where you can share the knowledge that you develop.  It would be a great help to people who want to help you with answers if you could add more details about what you are building, including perhaps pictures of the printer itself.  The more youcan tell us, the better each member can align their experience with your questions.  Could you please edit your question to add more detail?

Comment: Hello Sri, your question is not very clear, please update the question to make it more clear what you mean with *not using any commercial software* and the *parameters that I am supposed to choose*. Typically this is done by a slicer, there are open source and commercial software slicer applications that can do that for you. As the question is not clear it is put *on hold*, when you update the question it can be re-opened.

Comment: @sri-harsha Use the same parameter for 0.4mm nozzle.Slic3r will help you to get all parameters, just test if you printer can support vibrations and shaking.

Answer (score 3):

These parameters are not fixed. FDM printers are designed to work over a range speeds, feed rates, layer heights, extrusion temperatures, etc, depending on the type of print job and the filament type used. If you design a printer to work with fixed parameters, you are unlikely to get good results.